# How to release properly external resourses in Activities or Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am little confused. According to documentation, Activity's (or fragment) lifecycle have no guarantee, that **onStop**() and **onDestroy**() will be called before destroying. But some external resources needs to be released. For example: calling **MediaPlayer.release**().

Another example is a library for working with [beacons](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html).

There are **onDestroy** event is used:

```
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}
```

Is it good practice to rely on **onDestroy** method when you need to release some resources?

Answer (score 0):

**Better option is to release the resources in `onPause()` and lock/re-capture it in `onResume()`.**

If an activity does not even call `onPause()`, then that means it has stopped unexpectedly, or was force-closed. And then in most cases, the entire Application has been stopped. So, there is no running thread, which means that the resources have been released automatically. So, `onPause()` is possibly the best place to release resources.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you define the release logic in a separate method and call it from onPause(), 
You can do the same for the resources allocation logic in the method onResume()